# bulk update with store procedure using while loop

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I want to update a table with million of records with some optimization but i am unable to create a procedure .here is my script

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_f;
Delimiter //
create procedure test_f()
begin
DECLARE i INT unsigned DEFAULT 1;
while i < 10 do
update top 2000 test t
set 
t.total = 123

where t.total=0;
set i = i+1;
end while;      


END //
```

how can i use top or limit in my procedure.

Comment: Did you try using `limit 2000` with `update` statement?

Comment: i tried but i got syntex error where can i use limit clause

Answer (score 0):

You can use `limit` with your `update` statement.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_f;

Delimiter //

create procedure test_f()
begin
    DECLARE i INT unsigned DEFAULT 1;
    while i < 10 do
        update test t
        set t.total = 123
        where t.total=0
        limit 2000;

        set i = i+1;
    end while;      
end;
//

delimiter ;
```

Above procedure causes updating *first found* 2000 records only.
If you want to update records between 2000 and plus, you need to specify that in the limit clause, for example as `limit 2000, 2000` which updates records with row number from 2001 to 4000.

Comment: i want to update all the table but in batches of 2000